# Same IP, multiple Laravel installs in sub directories. How to rewrite using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out (learn) how to set up `.htaccess` so multiple Laravel installs could be run on the same IP by by using the URL (`/site_1`, `/site_2`) like:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/site_1
```

So far what I have realized that subsequent request for resources (like: `/css/app.css`) don't pass the rewrite rules and are lost. I have tried the `OR` flag to tie the request somehow to the url but then rules gets mixed up.

How could I get this to work?

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site_1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /site_1/public_html/public/$1       [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /aloe [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /site_2/public_html/public/$1       [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this block and try again. Hope this will work. It might need some modification for the path you want to access for css and js.

```
RewriteBase /site_1/public_html/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_1/public_html/public/$1       [L]
```

Comment: Thank, it is a step closer, I do some experimenting with this.

Comment: @EdmondTamas Welcome... :)